# sqlalchemy.exc.NoReferencedTableError: Foreign key associated with column X could not find table Y with which to generate a foreign key

Tags: python, sql, database, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I get the following error in my sqlalchemy schema

```
python manage.py db migrate
...
sqlalchemy.exc.NoReferencedTableError: Foreign key associated with column 
'ArxivPaperFigure.arxiv_id' could not find table 'papers' with which to 
generate a foreign key to target column 'arxiv_id'
```

I do not understand this error since the table papers is not new but existed before. I made a lot of changes, including giving the papers table a new table to inherit from, but the primary key in papers is still the same arxiv_id. Here is my papers table

```
class Papers(db.Model, Paper): 

    arxiv_id = db.Column(db.String(1000), primary_key=True)
    ...
```

and the table which points to this table is

```
class ArxivPaperFigure(db.Model): 
    __tablename__ = 'ArxivPaperFigure'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    arxiv_id = db.Column(db.String(1000), db.ForeignKey('papers.arxiv_id'))
```

I can solve the issue by re-writing the Foreign key

```
arxiv_id = db.Column(db.String(1000), db.ForeignKey(Papers.arxiv_id))
```

However, I have a lot of foreign keys and for some tables which also have these foreign keys this solution does not work. So I would like to understand why this error appears? The papers table does exist. If I use psql and print all tables with \d I find the line

```
public | papers  | table    | user
```

so why does this reference not work anymore?

Answer (score 14):

ok I was able to solve it by explicitly naming the Papers table

```
__tablename__ = 'papers'
```

not sure why this was suddenly necessary, since it all worked before, but with that fix everything works.

Answer (score 8):

For others' reference, if you are using schemas (e.g. Postgres) you might also have to specify it:

```py
# Assumes tables live in schema `my_schema`

arxiv_id = db.Column(db.String(1000), db.ForeignKey('my_schema.papers.arxiv_id'))
```

Comment: That was my issue. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly my issue. `if you are using schemas (e.g. Postgres) you might also have to specify it`

Comment: Thank you! This solves the issue with SQL Server and schemas